# How to store two arrays as a key-value pair in one object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to store two array's as a key-value pair into an object. Since push does not work with objects how do I achieve this ?

JAvascript

```
var data = {};
var array1 = ['name', 'lastname'];
var array2 = ['john','doe'];
```

Desired output:

```
console.log(data);
data: {
     name: john,
     lastname: doe
}
```

Comment: `array1.reduce((obj, key, index) => { obj[key] = array2[index]; return obj; }, {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control):

```js
var array1 = ['name', 'lastname'];
var array2 = ['john','doe'];
var data = array1.reduce((acc, value, i) => (acc[value] = array2[i], acc), {});
console.log(data);
```

The second argument to the `reduce` method is the initial value. The first argument is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which gets called once for each element of `array1`. `acc` is either the initial value, or the return value of the previous call. `value` is the current element of `array1`. `i` is the index of the current element. This function assigns the matching element of `array2` to a property of `acc`, and returns `acc` using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `thisArg` for the wanted object and assign key and value of the same index.

```js
var data = {},
    array1 = ['name', 'lastname'],
    array2 = ['john','doe'];
    
array1.forEach(function (k, i) {
    this[k] = array2[i];
}, data);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method for this, which accepts a `callback` method as parameter.

```js
var array1 = ['name', 'lastname'];
var array2 = ['john','doe'];
var data=array1.reduce(function(obj,elem,index){
    obj[elem]=array2[index];
    return obj;
},{});
console.log(data);
```